# Firestore Query Return Nothing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have my user authenticated and would like them to poll on some options. Each authenticated user would be registered in a document in a collection. This is a serverless frontend react app.

```
const handleSubmit = async () => {
  try {
    await setDoc(doc(db, "data", user), {
      user: user,
      behave: choice === "behave" ? 1 : 0,
      grimace: choice === "grimace" ? 1 : 0,
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
  }
  try {
    const q = query(collection(db, "data"), where("uid", "==", user));
    const snapShot = await getDocs(q);
    snapShot.forEach((doc) =>
      console.log(doc)
    )
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
  }
}
```

My idea is i would like to avoid duplicate poll by reference to the uid of the user. When querying data and I didn't see any error message nor I didn't see any `console.log(doc)`, please kindly advise me what I have done wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the User ID as `user` in the document but then querying on field `uid`. Either set the field name to `uid` or change your query to `user` field as shown below:

```
await setDoc(doc(db, "data", user), {
  uid: user, // <-- set field name to UID
  // ...
});


// query on "uid" field
const q = query(collection(db, "data"), where("uid", "==", user));
```

Comment: yeah, you are right